# Tools for graphicaly representing database structure

Tags: database, erd, database-diagramming

I have been asked to create a graphical representation of our database, I have looked at tools such as, [lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com).  Are there any good tools that I can use to graphically represent the database and it's relationships?

Comment: What about [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en)? Cheers

Comment: http://www.lucidchart.com is the working link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using MySQL then [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) will create Entity Relationship Diagrams from a database.

If you're using ["Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft SQL Server, and other databases that are compliant with Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/FX101759431033.aspx) then [Visio Professional](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/FX100487861033.aspx) will do this.  (Note - Visio Standard doesn't do this.)

Answer (score 1):

I have used Enterprise Architect and found it to be very helpful.  Take a look at http://www.sparxsystems.com I believe they have a free trial. It's powerful, but gets out of the way so you can take your whiteboard drawings and quickly put them into a version controlled system, create .pngs, etc.  They do reverse engineering of code and databases to generate models.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database brand, for example, the SQL Management Studio has a means to generate a graphical representation of SQL Server databases, MySQL workbench will do it for MySQL and so on. Among the paid generic alternatives I've liked [EMS tools](http://sqlmanager.net) (which has a version for SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Firebird) and [Dezign](http://www.datanamic.com) (which supports 12 databases)

Answer (score 1):

[Sybase Power Designer](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner) is what i use. It is most complete by my opinion but it is expensive.

Comment: +1 for Power Designer... very full-featured if you can afford it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/) web-based tool also.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Associates ERWin.  There is a logical and physical view and in the physical, the current database can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Some commercial tools will do this. Personally, I only know [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) from Sparx Systems. For feeware I can recommend [SQuirrel SQL client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). You might also want to look at the data base support of OpenOffice.